# My Sites FollowedSitesUrl

Tags: 2013, my-site

I seem to be having a weird problem with My Sites. When it finishes creating the my site, the button in the homepage redirects to

```
http://***/_layouts/15/MySite.aspx?MySiteRedirect=AllSites&PortalUrl=http%3A%2F%2F***%2F_layouts%2F15%2FMySite%2Easpx&Public=0
```

where I get the following error:

> Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.PropertyOrFieldNotInitializedException:
>   The property or field 'FollowedSitesUrl' has not been initialized.

When I go directly to the website `http://***/` it opens my site normally. Already tried to delete my site, and it recreates with the same error.

Any help is appreciated.

## EDIT

It seems with the operation from backup / restore, the db didn't get well configured. In case anyone comes here, I solved by reconfiguring the service.

Comment: Add your Edit as an answer. That way you can accept the answer and the question will show up as resolved in the future

Comment: Isn't that a great feeling ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems with the operation from backup / restore, the db didn't get well configured. In case anyone comes here, I solved by reconfiguring the service.